# What is the life cycle of a cheap mechanical relay

Tags: relay

What roughly is the range of switching cycles that a cheap relay [like the standard China ones for RPI and Arduino](https://www.amazon.de/Elegoo-Relaismodul-Optokoppler-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B01M8G4Y7Z/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=3RWKSJSVSEH8N&keywords=relais%20arduino&qid=1650037105&sprefix=relais%20arduino%2Caps%2C153&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExRTJKTzZRVFZCRk1MJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjk1MTA5MzBIWDdBNzI1WTJCUiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNzMzODYxUUc5VUk2UUtIWUNLJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) should withstand before breaking?

I assume it not to be higher than 50 - 100k. [The datasheet states 100k.](https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf)

What better alternatives can be used to power cycle e.g. a 230V - 200W heater around 500-1000 times per day?

Comment: a solid-state relay?

Comment: the quality of manufacture of devices on Amazon is always suspect ... your question is not really answerable ... downvoted for that reason ... `what are some alternatives to mechanical relays for switching 230V - 200W heater around 500-1000 times per day?` would be answerable

Comment: it will probably be an order of magnitude or two better when switching dry than switching under load. 1000 times a day? Use solid state! You can get an opto-isolated TRIAC module aka SSR aka Solid State Relay for not too much.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks, I will go for an opto-isolated TRIAC module for my needs. I think this answer can be used to my question.

Comment: @Neil_UK I will probably use an SSR with 2Hz PWM. I have so far not found any remarks that speak against doing that. SSR are said to have life cycles of around 100MIO. With 2x86400 switches per day that would correspond to around 2years. Eventually I can further reduce the switching to enhance the lifetime.